# How to replicate post request as seen in Chrome Inspect?

Tags: javascript, api, cookies, axios, postman

I'm trying to programatically authenticate myself for the Premier League fantasy game (https://fantasy.premierleague.com/). When I inspect the network tab in Chrome Inspect while logging in, I see the following post request and response..

General:
Request URL: https://users.premierleague.com/accounts/login/
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 302 
Remote Address: 151.101.86.217:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Headers:
accept-ranges: bytes
cache-control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0
content-length: 0
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
date: Sun, 31 Mar 2019 17:22:05 GMT
location: https://fantasy.premierleague.com/a/login?state=success
server: nginx/1.13.5
set-cookie: csrftoken=cjda9XUQ26ZiXWl0KUbk5GVNNVUSUQZCy70OMZn4TcjapME8pijv7cNI413bPHs8; expires=Sun, 29-Mar-2020 17:22:05 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/
set-cookie: messages="fa4474ff71c7bd5422bf64125057fbc6ed68c6b1$[[\"__json_message\"\0540\05425\054\"Successfully signed in as .\"]\054[\"__json_message\"\0540\05425\054\"You have signed out.\"]\054[\"__json_message\"\0540\05425\054\"Successfully signed in as .\"]]"; httponly; Path=/
set-cookie: sessionid=mruasqjsv9ru8r7qlqk5vauixkt3uq88; expires=Sun, 14-Apr-2019 17:22:05 GMT; httponly; Max-Age=1209600; Path=/
set-cookie: sudo="V1mmxfTng2qS:1hAe9l:Kn0n8h3dSwGH-Qv2RbGNn5MrwvE"; expires=Sun, 31-Mar-2019 20:22:05 GMT; httponly; Max-Age=10800; Path=/; secure
set-cookie: pl_profile=eyJzIjogIld6SXNNVFk1T1RZNU5qVmQ6MWhBZTlsOll5aU4zQ3BWb1A0a3l2ZDZUS09LLUNyeHJhdyIsICJ1IjogeyJsbiI6ICJMaW5kYmVyZyIsICJmYyI6IDMsICJpZCI6IDE2OTk2OTY1LCAiZm4iOiAiSmltIn19; Domain=premierleague.com; expires=Sun, 14-Apr-2019 17:22:05 GMT; Max-Age=1209600; Path=/; secure
status: 302
vary: Cookie
via: 1.1 google
via: 1.1 varnish
x-cache: MISS
x-cache-hits: 0
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-served-by: cache-bma1634-BMA

Request Headers
:authority: users.premierleague.com
:method: POST
:path: /accounts/login/
:scheme: https
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: sv-SE,sv;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
cache-control: max-age=0
content-length: 186
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
cookie: _ga=GA1.2.963283199.1544268407; _gid=GA1.2.530727258.1554052864; csrftoken=xRErJTDda0drIGPICOjvXMHhkjjRRmsO74wbhoZBmKbz5zpHATuVJQ3sTWIIvaXf; messages="956228cd3e90b2b498670e8d2101699bcec07800$[[\"__json_message\"\0540\05425\054\"Successfully signed in as .\"]\054[\"__json_message\"\0540\05425\054\"You have signed out.\"]]"; _gat=1; _gat_UA-33785302-1=1
origin: http://evil.com/
referer: https://fantasy.premierleague.com/?fail
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36

Form Data: 
csrfmiddlewaretoken: OFwVFKPSkKc0AG1hxHekpCSWb1l3Wl35
login: 
password: 
app: plfpl-web
redirect_uri: https://fantasy.premierleague.com/a/login

I'm trying to replicate this post request using Javascript and Axios. I have the following code:

```
authPLfantasy() {
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('password', '<password>');
        formData.append('login', '<username>');
        formData.append('redirect_uri', 'https://fantasy.premierleague.com/a/login');
        formData.append('app', 'plfpl-web');

        let config = {
            url: 'https://users.premierleague.com/accounts/login',
            method: 'post',
            withCredentials: true,
            data: formData
        };

        return axios.request(config);
    }
```

The result I get when log the result of this function is: "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://users.premierleague.com/accounts/login' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute."

I'm vaguely familiar with CORS so I think I can solve it if I bang my head long and hard enough against the wall but I heard that sending the post request through Postman would not be affected by CORS so I tried using that instead just to see if I could get that to work. While I receive a 200 OK response using Postman, I don't get the correct response, crucially I'm missing the cookies pl_profile and sessionid. Changed form data in Postman so that password or username is invalid still renders a 200 OK response.

The end goal is, using Javascript, to send the post request after a user submits the necessary credentials after clicking a button in my React app. The necessary cookies should be generated so that the app subsequently can send a get request to a different auth protected endpoint and retrieve the information from there. I feel like it shouldn't be that hard but I just can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: What's the actual response in Postman? Also, the quickest way around the CORS issue is using a backend proxy to make the `post` call. Since you're using JS I'd recommend Node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Chrome, perhaps the easiest thing is to

1. Open Chrome Dev Tools
2. Go to the Network tab
3. Select the request you'd like to replicate
4. Right click and select "Copy > Copy as cURL"
5. Open a Terminal, paste the command and execute it

[image]